# Is there a better way to get the last level of groups from a table?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have a Group table and within that table, there is a ParentId column that denotes a groups parent within the Group table. The purpose is to build a dynamic menu from these groups. I know I can loop and grab the last child and construct a result set, but I'm curious if there's a more SQL-y way of accomplishing this.

The table has Id, ParentId and Title fields of int, int and varchar.

Basically, a hierarchy may be constructed this way (People is the base group):

```
People -> Male   -> Boy
                 -> Man
       -> Female
```

I want to grab the last child(ren) of each branch. So, {Boy, Man, Female} in this case.

As I mentioned, *getting* that info isn't a problem. I'm just looking for a better way of getting it without having to write a bunch of unions and loops where I can basically change the base group and traverse the entire hierarchy outward, dynamically. I'm not really a Db guy, so I don't know if there's a slick way of doing this or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the leaf levels for one of many hierarchies, you can use a [Recursive Common Table Expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243%28v=SQL.105%29.aspx) (CTEs) to enumerate the hierarchy, and then check which members are not the parent of another group to filter to the leaves:

```
Declare @RootID int = 1

;with cte as (
  select 
    Id,
    ParentId,
    Title
  From
    Groups
  Where
    Id = @RootID
  Union All
  Select
    g.Id, 
    g.ParentId,
    g.Title
  From
    cte c
      Inner Join
    Groups g
      On c.Id = g.ParentID
)
Select
  *
From
  cte g
Where
  Not Exists (
    Select
      'x'
    From
      Groups g2
    Where
      g2.ParentID = g.Id
  );
```

You can also do this with a left join rather than a not exists

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8f1aa/9

Comment: Thanks for the answer. One question: how do I only get these results for Person, though? This will give me all of the last level of all hierarchies.

Comment: @Yatrix Updated to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using SQL Server 2012 you could take advantage of [`hierarchyid`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677290.aspx); here is an example following Laurence's schema:

```
CREATE TABLE Groups
    (
      Id INT NOT NULL
             PRIMARY KEY
    , Title VARCHAR(20)
    , HID HIERARCHYID
    )

INSERT  INTO Groups
VALUES  ( 1, 'People', '/' ),
        ( 2, 'Male', '/1/' ),
        ( 3, 'Female', '/2/' ),
        ( 4, 'Boy', '/1/1/' ),
        ( 5, 'Man', '/1/2/' );

SELECT  Id
      , Title
FROM    Groups
WHERE   HID NOT IN ( SELECT HID.GetAncestor(1)
                     FROM   Groups
                     WHERE  HID.GetAncestor(1) IS NOT NULL )
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/00330/1/0

Results:

```
ID  TITLE
3   Female
4   Boy
5   Man
```

Comment: I'm not looking to change the table. Thanks for the suggestion, though. Have to keep this in mind.